# when i call api result is json with empty object solve this problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

[image]

when I call api the result is empty object

here is my code

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  const user = User.find({}, function(err, users){

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(users);
        }
    });
});

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  User.create(req.body).then(user => {
    res.send(user);
  }).catch(next);
});
```

I hope this will help you. Or if you want to assign a variable.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  const {username, password, email, phone} = req.body;
  User.create(req.body).then(user => {
    res.send({username, password, email, phone});
  }).catch(next);
});
```